Is there a way to change a generic function through the Unity inspector?
I have a StateMachine component that includes a list of "transitions". Each transition includes an origin state, a condition, and a target state. The transition should happen if the object is in the origin state, and the condition evaluates to true.
Currently, I use System.Func<bool> for the condition. But it does not appear in the inspector, so I cannot change it from there.
How can I define a generic condition, that can be changed via the inspector?

https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/6000.0/Documentation/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html

@Evorlor In this case, the function must be able to return a boolean in order for the calling code to check whether the condition was met. UnityAction and UnityEvent.Invoke are both void, so they can't serve this role, at least not in the most obvious way. Is there a particular way you would employ these types to get around this constraint?

I'm curious whether you've evaluated using Unity's built-in Mechanim state machine and StateMachineBehaviours for this, since they already implement conditions and state transitions in a very flexible way. If those are unsuitable for your needs, a little more detail about your use case and the kinds of conditions you need could help users here design something better-suited for your use.

I have handled similar cases in the past by using an interface and the [SerializeReference] attribute. Something like this:
public interface ICondition
{
    public bool Evaluate();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ConditionA : ICondition
{
    public bool Evaluate()
    {
        // check whatever
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ConditionB : ICondition
{
    public bool Evaluate()
    {
        // check whatever
    }
}

Which you then would use like this:
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeReference] ICondition condition;

    public bool CheckCondition()
    {
        return condition.Evaluate();
    }
}

One inconvenient thing with this approach is that you will need an appropriate drawer for the polymorphic reference. Searching on google for "SerializeReference drawer" returns many alternatives for this, but I won't endorse any specific one.
Also, I guess this is a somewhat inefficient way to handle things, as you are creating a separate, heap-allocated object just to represent a function call... But this is most likely not going to be relevant at all.

Is there a way to handle lambda expressions with this method? I.e., I want the condition to be () => some_random_number < 0.9

You could have any fields you want as part of the condition, and have those be serialized in the inspector as well (so, that 0.9 threshold, for example), and then pass the variable you want to compare as an argument to the Evaluate method. As for actually writing a lambda in the inspector... I guess you could theoretically parse it with reflection, but that is significantly more complicated.

@ErelSegal-Halevi Which object has the some_random_number property that you want to read? If you have a controlled set of properties that can be used in these comparisons, we may be able to architect an efficient way to select and fetch them. If you need a fully generic solution then you might need to rely on runtime reflection as PepeOjeda suggests or code generation, either of which is much more complicated. Editing your question to include more specifics of your use case can help us better tailor solutions to your particular needs.

@DMGregory By "some_random_number" I meant something like Random.Range(0,1)
